# Try to find an element in the list based on a part of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list = ['Assassin Bow', 'Bone Bow', 'Citadel Bow']
and I have a string = 'Bone Bow of Fire'

How can I get output 'Bone Bow' as the result ?
Just started codding, thx for understanding.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If not, I suggest you start by writing in words the steps you would take to do this yourself. Pretend that I give you the list and string. How would you go about solving the problem by hand?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
l = ['Assassin Bow', 'Bone Bow', 'Citadel Bow']
s = 'Bone Bow of Fire'

# loop through each element in list 'l'
for x in l:
    # if the element is somewhere in the string 's'
    if x in s:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, my hero!

Answer (score 2):

You can check iteratively to see if an element in list is included in string or not.

The very basic is to use a for loop:

```
result = []
for item in list:
    if item in string:
        result.append(item)
```

A more comprehensive way:

```
result = [i for i in l if i in s]
```

This will return a list containing all elements that satisfies the condition. In your example, it will be a list of one item, but for other cases, there can be more.

Notes:

- `list` is a predefined function/class in python, so do NOT name your variables with it.
- `string` is technically allowed, but it's a better practice not to use it. You should name your variables cleverer and more meaningful.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yeah, my bad, `string` was definitely not (probably wrote the answer too quick), but it's a better practice to not use it anyways and give a better name to your variable.